# Simple async I/O handler is dropping requests

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, node.js, asynchronous

I've written a small .ashx handler in C#, with straight-forward logic:

- Generate a random payload string of 54 kilobytes.
- Get a unique filename to store the data.
- Write the string to file in async manner.
- Read back from that file in async manner.
- Send that string back to response stream.

The idea is to throw multiple concurrent requests to the above handler using apache-bench, so that I can compare ASP.NET 4.5 against other frameworks (like nodejs) for a large-size app I'm going to develop which is heavily I/O bound. Here is the code for the Handler:

```
public class Handler : System.Web.IHttpHandler
{
    private StringBuilder payload = null;

    private async void processAsync()
    {
        var r = new Random ();

        //generate a random string of 108kb
        payload=new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < 54000; i++)
            payload.Append( (char)(r.Next(65,90)));

        //create a unique file
        var fname = "";
        do{fname = "c:\\source\\csharp\\asyncdemo\\" + r.Next (1, 99999999).ToString () + ".txt";
        } while(File.Exists(fname));            

        //write the string to disk in async manner
        using(FileStream fs = File.Open(fname,FileMode.CreateNew,FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            var bytes=(new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ()).GetBytes (payload.ToString());
            await fs.WriteAsync (bytes,0,bytes.Length);
            fs.Close ();
        }

        //read the string back from disk in async manner
        payload = new StringBuilder ();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (fname);
        payload.Append(await sr.ReadToEndAsync ());
        sr.Close ();
        //File.Delete (fname); //remove the file
    }

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
        Task task = new Task(processAsync);
        task.Start ();
        task.Wait ();

        //write the string back on the response stream
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write (payload.ToString());
    }


    public bool IsReusable 
    {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The trouble is that the Handler runs perfectly when I compile it and run from my browser once. But when I send concurrent requests to it using ab, about half the requests get dropped. Not only that, but its way too slow compared to a similar script I've written in node.js - I've tested it both on IIS-7/Windows and Mono/Linux environments. Do you suggest ASP.NET is inherently slower compared to node.js to handle heavy async I/O load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reimplemented my code in the following manner, and it works now:

```
private StringBuilder payload = null;

private async void processAsync()
{
    var r = new Random (DateTime.Now.Ticks.GetHashCode());

    //generate a random string of 108kb
    payload=new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < 54000; i++)
        payload.Append( (char)(r.Next(65,90)));

    //create a unique file
    var fname = "";
    do
    {
        //fname = @"c:\source\csharp\asyncdemo\" + r.Next (1, 99999999).ToString () + ".txt";
        fname =  r.Next (1, 99999999).ToString () + ".txt";
    } while(File.Exists(fname));            

    //write the string to disk in async manner
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(fname,FileMode.CreateNew,FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
        bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
        var bytes=(new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ()).GetBytes (payload.ToString());
        await fs.WriteAsync (bytes,0,bytes.Length);
        fs.Close ();
    }

    //read the string back from disk in async manner
    payload = new StringBuilder ();
    //FileStream ;
    //payload.Append(await fs.ReadToEndAsync ());
    using (var fs = new FileStream (fname, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
               FileShare.Read, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true)) {
        int numRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
        while ((numRead = await fs.ReadAsync (buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) {
            payload.Append (Encoding.Unicode.GetString (buffer, 0, numRead));
        }
    }


    //fs.Close ();
    //File.Delete (fname); //remove the file
}

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
{
    Task task = new Task(processAsync);
    task.Start ();
    task.Wait ();

    //write the string back on the response stream
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write (payload.ToString());
}
```